# How to execute Core Data NSFetchRequest in a class method?

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, core-data, swiftui

I have `AppName.xcdatamodeld` file, with `Category` in `Entities`. In `Category` I successfully add records from SwiftUI and successfully fetch them in `View` like so:

```
import SwiftUI
import CoreData

struct CategoriesList: View {
    @Environment(\.managedObjectContext) var moc
    
    var fetchRequest: FetchRequest<CountdownCategory>
    var countdownCategories: FetchedResults<CountdownCategory> {
        fetchRequest.wrappedValue
    }
    
    var body: some View {
        ForEach(countdownCategories, id: \.self) { countdownCategory in
            Text(countdownCategory.title ?? "Category")
        }
    }
    
    init() {
        fetchRequest = FetchRequest<CountdownCategory>(entity: CountdownCategory.entity(), sortDescriptors: [NSSortDescriptor(keyPath: \CountdownCategory.dateAdded, ascending: false)])
    }
}
```

Now I need to execute same query in different place of a program - not in SwiftUI view, but in a method in a class:

```
import Foundation
import CoreData

class Categories {
    func getCategories() {
        let moc = NSManagedObjectContext(concurrencyType: .mainQueueConcurrencyType)
        let categoriesFetch = NSFetchRequest<NSFetchRequestResult>(entityName: "CountdownCategory")
         
        do {
            let categoriesFetch = try moc.fetch(categoriesFetch) as! [CountdownCategory]
        } catch {
            fatalError("Failed to fetch categories: \(error)")
        }
        
        // etc.
    }
}
```

I looked up sample code in [official Core Data documentation](https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/CoreData/FetchingObjects.html), however when I try to execute this I get an error:

> *** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '+entityForName: nil is not a legal NSPersistentStoreCoordinator for searching for entity name 'CountdownCategory''

Would appreciate any help with fixing that error. My goal is to get data from Core Data from `CountdownCategory` in this method. (Swift 5.2)

UPD #1: when I use `let categoriesFetch = CountdownCategory.fetchRequest()` I get an error:

> Ambiguous use of 'fetchRequest()'

UPD #2: when I use `let categoriesFetch: NSFetchRequest<CountdownCategory> = CountdownCategory.fetchRequest()` I do not get a crash. But how do I get data?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
let moc = NSManagedObjectContext(concurrencyType: .mainQueueConcurrencyType)
```

You're making a brand new managed object context here, with no backing persistent store or model. That's not the right way to do it. You need to use the same context you passed in to your SwiftUI environment object, wherever that came from.

You've said that the app delegate has an `NSPersistentContainer` so I'm guessing you've used the SwiftUI / Core Data app template. In that case you need to replace the line of code above (`let moc = ...`) with something like this:

```
let moc = (UIApplication.shared.delegate as! AppDelegate).persistentContainer.viewContext
```

If you are using the template, you can look in **SceneDelegate.swift** and see where the context is injected into the SwiftUI environment using similar code.

Comment: I pass environment object to View like so: `CategoriesList().environment(\.managedObjectContext, moc)`, but I struggle to declare it/use it in method.

Comment: where does `moc` in the of code in your comment come from? That's the instance you need to use in the class method

Comment: It comes from `@Environment(\.managedObjectContext) var moc` in a view before `var body: some View {`...

Comment: you need to follow that up the chain until you find where it is created in the first place. Does your app have an `NSPersistentContainer` anywhere?

Comment: Yes, in `AppDelegate.swift` in Core Data Stack section, `let container = NSPersistentCloudKitContainer(name: "MyTitle")`